# Duhamels principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a problem with the following exercise (I know how to proof for $u_{tt}$ but for $u_t$ I met a problem, for $u_{tt}$ proof works as we can assume that $v(x,t,t)=0$ and we add it artificially to the equation, when here this trick doesn't work...)

Prove Duhamels principle:

for $s> 0$ let $v(x; t; s)$ be the solution of the following initial-boundary problem (which depends on the parameter s):
$$ v_t - v_{xx} = 0;         0 < x < L; t > s;$$ 
$$ v(0; t; s) = v(L; t; s) = 0; t > s;$$ 
$$ v(x; s; s) = F(x; s); 0<x<L$$

Prove that the function
$$ u(x; t) = \int_0^t v(x; t; s)ds$$ 
is a solution of the nonhomogeneous problem:
$$u_t - u_{xx} = F(x; t); 0 < x < L; t > 0;$$ $$u(0; t) = u(L; t) = 0 t > 0;$$
$$u(x; 0) = 0; 0<x<L$$

Comment: I've tried to solve it as follows: $u(0,t) = \int_0^t v(0;t;s) ds=0$ , $u(L,t) = \int_0^t v(L;t;s) ds=0$ ,  $u(x,0) = \int_0^t v(x;0;s) ds=0$ . Then I tried with the main equation: $u_t − u_{xx} = \int_0^t v_t (x;t;s) - v_{xx} (x;t;s) ds$ but it should be equal to zero accoring to   $v_t − v{xx}$ ...

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating $u$ twice with respect to x we get

$$u_{xx}(x,t)= \int_{0}^{t}v_{xx}(x,t,s)ds.$$

Differentiating $u$ once with respect to t we get

$$u_{t}(x,t)= \int_{0}^{t}v_{t}(x,t,s)ds+v(x,t,t),$$

where the second term is a consequence of Leibniz's rule for differentiating an integral with variable limits.

Subtracting, we get

$$u_{t}(x,t)-u_{xx}(x,t)= \int_{0}^{t}[v_{t}(x,t,s)-v_{xx}(x,t,s)]ds+v(x,t,t).$$

and

$$u_{t}(x,t)-u_{xx}(x,t)= F(x,t),$$

because the integrand vanishes and $v$ has initial condition $v(x,t,t)=F(x,t)$.

Comment: Hello, I am confused about $\mu_t-\mu_{xx}=F(x,t)$, since we have $v_t=v_{xx}$ for $t>s$, why it still valid for $t>0$.